# Show revision number on area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

One of the things I liked about SO was the openness to post the revision number on the website. I'd love it if Area51 would do the same.

[image: example]

Comment: We should also get to see the revision number of of the SE policy...  :-)

Comment: @Jared Thanks for the pictures.